# Ansible: How to change active directory in Ansible Playbook?

Tags: ansible

```
- name: Go to the folder
  command: chdir=/opt/tools/temp
```

When I run my playbook, I get:

```
TASK: [Go to the folder] ***************************** 
failed: [host] => {"failed": true, "rc": 256}
msg: no command given
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with changing active dir?

Comment: also the chdir is an attribute of command. You can do command and also  declare the chdir `command: ls chdir=/path/to/directory`

Comment: This has nothing to do with Microsoft's ActiveDirectory, does it?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

There's no concept of current directory in Ansible. You can specify current directory for specific task, like you did in your playbook. The only missing part was the actual command to execute. Try this:

```
- name: Go to the folder and execute command
  command: chdir=/opt/tools/temp ls
```

Comment: Good to have ability to run all playbook within a specific directory

Comment: `"There's no concept of current directory in Ansible"` I don't think that's true anymore, LOTS of tasks take relative paths now, such as `npm` `composer` `bower` etc

Comment: The pwd seems to be at the location of the playbook, irregardless of from which path you execute the `ansible-playbook` command?

Answer (score 44):

This question was in the results for when I was trying to figure out why 'shell' was not respecting my `chdir` entries when I had to revert to Ansible 1.9. So I will be posting my solution.

I had

```
- name: task name
  shell:
    cmd: touch foobar
    creates: foobar
    chdir: /usr/lib/foobar
```

It worked with Ansible > 2, but for 1.9 I had to change it to.

```
- name: task name
  shell: touch foobar
  args:
    creates: foobar
    chdir: /usr/lib/foobar
```

Just wanted to share.

Answer (score 10):

If you need a login console (like for bundler), then you have to do the command like this.

`command: bash -lc "cd /path/to/folder && bundle install"`

Comment: This is also the command to use with composer (if the composer module doesn't get you there):

`command: bash -lc "cd /var/www/ && /usr/local/bin/composer install"`

Comment: You can now user `working_dir` to specify composer path relative

Answer (score 10):

You can change into a directory before running a command with ansible with [`chdir`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/command_module.html#parameter-chdir).

Here's an example I just setup:

```
- name: Run a pipenv install
  environment:
    LANG: "en_GB.UTF-8"
  command: "pipenv install --dev"
  args:
    chdir: "{{ dir }}/proj"
```