# How do you get a command defined in YAML to run one of two functions with Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unix, ansible, yaml

Right now, I'm just trying to set up a YAML script that simply checks if a particular node package is installed or not. The way I currently have it is:

```
command: npm list selenium-webdriver >/dev/null || npm install selenium-webdriver
```

However, this always returns:

```
fatal: [localhost -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": ["npm", "ls", "selenium-webdriver", ">/dev/null", "||", "npm", "install", "selenium-webdriver"], "delta": "0:00:00.463110", "end": "2017-08-09 12:56:30.359529", "failed": true, "rc": 1, "start": "2017-08-09 12:56:29.896419", "stderr": "npm ERR! code 1", "stdout": "/myDir\n└── (empty)", "stdout_lines": ["/myDir", "└── (empty)"], "warnings": []}
```

I'm not entirely sure what an "npm ERR! code 1" error even is.

I tried to shorten it to see what the error might be, can it seems to be the argument:

```
npm list selenium-webdriver
```

I was hoping that it would run the first command, and IF that failed, then run the second command (the installation).

How exactly do I go about doing such that this command acts in the manner I'm looking for?

Comment: There is no such thing as a YAML script. You seem to be confusing something that is using a  YAML document as its input with "YAML doing something". It makes as much sense to ask "How do you get UTF-8 to run two functions with Node.js" or ask about an "ASCII script".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't better to use `npm` module?

```
- npm:
    name: selenium-webdriver
    path: /app/location
```

`npm` module is idempotent and it will only install the `selenium-webdriver` if it is not installed already.

Comment: I do not have permissions to use this. I'm not the administrator. So this method won't work.

Comment: in the above mentioned command, you are doing the same thing `npm install selenium-webdriver`?

Comment: I think it's the global part that gives me the error. What should be done if you set the global variable to no, instead of yes?

Comment: you can remove the global line and then run it

Comment: This is the output: fatal: [localhost -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "path must be specified when not using global"}

Comment: I solved it using this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19369931/ansible-how-to-change-active-directory-in-ansible-playbook

Comment: check the updated answer, it will help you, I got your point that you want to install it in custom location