# Change current directory and stay there

Tags: ansible, cd, ansible-tower

I am trying to run an ansible script to install confluent from ansible tower.  When I run the script from the server directly, I go into the directory /software/cp-ansible and then run the playbook.  When I want to run the same install from tower, it lands in user's home directory.  So, I tried to add a cd command to the ansible script before it continues with the installation.  But Ansible doesn't seem to stay in the directory changed to by "cd" command when that tasks completes.

How can I stay in the "changed directory" to be  able  to continue?  Or is there a way in Tower template where I can indicate to change directory before running the script?

**Update**

I have a task  before this install task to cd to cp-ansible, but it goes back to the home directory after that task completes

When running from Tower,  this is the place where it fails

```
{
    "_ansible_no_log": false,
    "msg": "Hash Merging must be enabled in ansible.cfg: Confirm current directory is cp-ansible and permissions are set to 755 not 777",
    "changed": false,
    "assertion": "lookup('config', 'DEFAULT_HASH_BEHAVIOUR') == 'merge'",
    "evaluated_to": false
}
```

The suggested question *[Ansible: How to change active directory in Ansible Playbook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19369931/ansible-how-to-change-active-directory-in-ansible-playbook)*  does have the command to change directory, but after the task completes, it doesn't stay in the changed directory.  Hence it is not the same

Comment: I am afraid this is not possible, you will have to set the directory you want to act on for each tasks. Also see [Ansible: How to change active directory in Ansible Playbook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19369931/ansible-how-to-change-active-directory-in-ansible-playbook)

Comment: As I updated the question explaining why this is not a duplicate.  Not sure, why this is still marked as duplicate

Comment: Two reason: 1. because of the way SO works, when you post a new question, and because we all have our expertise, you get noticed by the persons more likely to be able to answer your question. When you edit the question, it gets send to a review queue, where people with enough reputation can vote if your edit makes your question more likely to be answered or not. Because this review queue is quite crowded and because the reviewers are less likely to be knoledgeable on the subject at hand, this means that the reopening of a question tends to be slower than the closing of it.

Comment: 2. Because you can add as much details as you want in your question, the answer stays the same, it is not possible because Ansible does not have a current directory, as you seems to think it does. This is clearly pointed in the answer of the duplicate question.

Comment: But you don't have to believe me or the other answerer. If you want you can try it out by yourself: you first have to understand how ansible works: for each task, it **will** generate a new ssh connection. So you can do the same as Ansible. `ssh` to your server. `cd` to any folder you'd like to be. `exit` out of the current ssh session. Re `ssh` to the same server. Are you still in the folder you `cd`'ed before? No, then nor will ansible be.

Comment: And if you don't believe me about ansible running one ssh command per task, just run your playbook with the `-vvvv` extra verbosity switch, and you'll see the multiple `ssh` connections that ansible use internally.

Comment: Sorry, I did not want to convey that I did not believe.   I did believe you and if you had that as an answer, instead of comment,  I would definitely have accepted it as an answer immediately.  The reason, I was wondering why it is marked duplicate is that from the linked answer, it did not clarify that it doesn't stay in the directory which was my basic question.  In fact,  I had found and used the linked answer to do the "cd" successfully, but the next task still gave the error above,  hence I posted the new question.  I did accept you first comment to be true.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε -   I have just begun using Ansible  and was not familiar with the fact that each task generates a new ssh connection.  Thank you for that piece of information as well.