# change directory in ansible playbook

Tags: linux, ansible

i have ansible playbook and i want to look at specified directory (with ls command). the directory is in the root, i check with the pwd command :

```
/root/git/ansible/data/example
```

and the ansible the task looks like this :

```
name:  open directory
become: yes
become_user: root
command: chdir=/data/example ls
```

after i execute the playbook i get this error :

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unable to change directory before execution: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/data/example'"}
```

while the directory actually does exist. i also tried this :

```
name:  open directory
become: yes
become_user: root
shell:
  cmd: ls
  chdir: /data/example
```

and got the same error. can anyone help?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19369931/ansible-how-to-change-active-directory-in-ansible-playbook

Comment: It's not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19369931/ansible-how-to-change-active-directory-in-ansible-playbook). The error is ``'No command given'`` because the command is missing ``command: chdir=/opt/tools/temp``. Here, the problem is ``'No such file or directory'``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the tree

```sh
shell> tree /data/example
/data/example
├── file1
├── file2
└── file3

0 directories, 3 files
```

all forms of *command* and *shell*

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - command:
        chdir: /data/example
        cmd: ls
      register: result
      tags: t1

    - shell:
        chdir: /data/example
        cmd: ls
      register: result
      tags: t2

    - command: chdir=/data/example ls
      register: result
      tags: t3

    - shell: chdir=/data/example ls
      register: result
      tags: t4

    - debug:
        var: result.stdout
      tags: always
```

work as expected

```yaml
  result.stdout:
    file1
    file2
    file3
```